# Copy rowtype variable to another

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have

```
l_tab1 table1%rowtype;
l_tab2 table2%rowtype;
```

The structures of table1 and table2 are the same.

How can move the data from l_tab1 to the l_tab2 ?

now I can see two ways but I don't like it because I need hardcoded the fields.

## 1

```
l_tab2.field1 := l_tab1.field1;
l_tab2.field2 := l_tab1.field2;
```

## 2

```
select * into l_tab2
from table1
where field1 = l_tab1.field1
  and field2 = l_tab1.field2;
```

## 3

I believe it should be much easier like

```
insert into l_tab2
values l_tab1;
```

or something like that without using the fields.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand something, but I created a test example and `l_tab2 := l_tab1;` worked for me. The version is 11.2 XE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the two tables have the same structure, a simple assignment should work, at least from Oracle 11.2 on.

With tables like the following

```
create table table1(col1 number, col2 number);
create table table2(col1 number, col2 number);

insert into table1 values (1, 11);
insert into table2 values (2, 22);
```

we have:

```
SQL> select * from table1;

      COL1       COL2
---------- ----------
         1         11

SQL> select * from table2;

      COL1       COL2
---------- ----------
         2         22

SQL> declare
  2      l_tab1  table1%rowtype;
  3      l_tab2  table2%rowtype;
  4  begin
  5      select *
  6      into l_tab1
  7      from table1;
  8      l_tab2 := l_tab1;
  9      insert into table2 values l_tab2;
 10  end;
 11  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from table2;

      COL1       COL2
---------- ----------
         1         11
         2         22

SQL>
```

Comment: I forgot you could assign from one `ROWTYPE` record to another. More info: https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/working-with-records

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works very well. If selects have the same structure we can operate rowtype variables like it's the same. Cool!

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to do what you want without specifying each column.

A workaround might be to use a collection rather than a record type. Each collection might only have 1 record, but you'll be able to do that without specifying each column.

This answer has a more complex example, but roughly what you'd need.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18700073/1811001